# How to get a timezone aware date in django templates?

Tags: django, timezone

I have a django template, which looks like this:

```
{{ object.created.date }}
```

But the date is not timezone aware, i.e. "10.06.2016"

```
{{ object.created }}
```

is a datetime with the correct timezone, i.e. "11.06.2016 00:30"

The `|localtime` filter returns the some date for the second case, but an empty string for the first one. using `with` to define a variable with the filtered datetime and then using `myfiltereddatetime.date` gives an empty string as well.

Comment: Not familiar with django but would it be possible to use epoch time? Epoch is a good resource since it is timezone independent.

Comment: In settings, is `USE_L10N = True`?

Comment: Yes, it is. I solved it for now by formatting this via ``created|format:SHORT_DATE_FORMAT``, but it seems a bit unclean, because the native date object should work. Using epoch time is not useful, as i WANT the timezone. Django handles timezones, but it seems it's inconsistent between the whole datetime object and the ``datetime.date`` part.